# rails 3.2 ActionView MissingTemplate only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, production-environment, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an application that works beautifully in development mode.  In an attempt to test in production in Webrick or Passenger/apache most of my site loads well until I try to submit an ajax form.  I have properly used bundle install --deployment.  I've properly precompiled my assets.  But for some reason I'm getting the following error when submitting remote forms.  Keep in mind, the ajax is actually working as it is creating records in the database.  One thing I find interesting is that I am using a gemset with ruby 1.9.3 but I am getting references to ruby 1.9.1 in these error codes.  I'm also including the Users controller so you can see the controller references. Help!

**Update!!** Depending on what action whether it be the create action, edit action update action or destroy the error is missing template users/create or users/update or users/edit users/destroy etc.  Read comment on the first answer as I believe this is an issue with the javascript files not being included in the precompile process.

```
Started GET "/users/5" for 24.163.20.124 at 2012-02-07 03:30:09 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 58ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
* "/home/ctilley/Development/RatatouilleCatering/app/views"
* "/home/ctilley/Development/RatatouilleCatering/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/wash_out-0.3.1/app/views"
* "/home/ctilley/Development/RatatouilleCatering/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ckeditor-3.7.0.rc2/app/views"
):
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:28:in `determine_template'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `_render_template'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :require_user
  respond_to :html, :js
  load_and_authorize_resource
def index
  @users = User.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page=>params[:page])

   authorize! :read, @article
end

def show
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  if @user.save
  respond_with @user, :location => users_url
  end
end

def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy

  respond_with @user, :location => users_url
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_with @user, :location => users_url
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

  respond_with @user, :location => users_url
end
private
def sort_column
  params[:sort] || "id"
end
def sort_direction
   params[:direction] || "asc"
 end

end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

move the following outside of the assets group in your Gemfile

```
gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.2.1"
gem 'uglifier', ">= 1.0.3"
```

Comment: What's the explanation for this?

Comment: @Lyudmil I don't know.  It only affected me in this particular version

Answer (score -1):

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/show...)
```

This means that view file app/users/show.html.erb is missing. Create a dummy file here and see if this solves the problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case.  The respond_with statement forces these actions on the index. All of this works great in development mode as indicated above. Edit, update, create are remote forms that call the corresponding index.js.coffee create.js.coffee update.js.coffee and destroy.js.coffee. These reside in the view folder for that particular controller.  What I am thinking is that these javascript files are not being compiled during the precompile process.  Therefore the records are posted, but the javascript is not executed. I need to find a way to add these files to asset/precompile path.